# How can i get text of 2nd column if i will provide the text of 1st column

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I have a table containing 2 columns. 1st column contains the type of amount i.e book fees, registration fees, and 2nd column contains the amount i.e 500 and 400.I want to get the text of 2nd column(amount), how can i get text of 2nd column by providing the text of 1st column?Just giving the xpath of 2nd column is not working for me because of dynamic data sets.

xpaths of type of amounts are:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")).getText();  (text=Book Fee)
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]")).getText(); (text= Registration fees)
```

xpaths of amounts are:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).getText();  (text= 500.00/=)
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")).getText(); (text=1000.00/=)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XPath for `Book Fee` fees:

```
//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tr/td[text()='Book Fee']/../td[2]
```

Try the following XPath for `Registration fees` fees:

```
//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tr/td[text()='Registration fees']/../td[2]
```

You can parameterize the first column value to make it work for all using String concatanation :

```
//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tr/td[text()=' " + feeType + "']/../td[2]
```

here `feeType`, is the value you pass as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question and the *HTML* you have shared, you can extract the text **Book Fee** and **Registration fees** through your code as follows :

```
String bookFeeText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")).getText();
String registrationFeeText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]")).getText();
```

Now, to retrieve the text of the next columns you can take help of the text you have extracted out of the previous colums as follows :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[.='" + bookFeeText + "']//following::td[1]")).getText();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[.='" + registrationFeeText + "']//following::td[1]")).getText();
```

Comment: But these xpaths are not static. thats why some time the fees of registration is shown in book fees.how can i get the text by not giving the xpath but by giving the text.like if it contains text 'book fee' it should get text which is infront of it

Comment: What do you mean by _xpaths are not static_? _xpath_ are written by end users to traverse the _DOM_. Of-coarse this is a dynamic _xpath_ as per your requirement. Your absolute _xpaths_ were clear so I made out the relative _xpath_ else it won't have been possible to provide you an answer anyway. Check out my Answer and let me know the status.

Comment: An exception is generation :org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[.='   Book Fee']//following::td[1]"}

Comment: In my solution it's **bookFeeText** but not `Book Fee`.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to get the amount against the Type of fee, regardless of its position in the table.

```
List <WebElement> fee_List=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr"));
WebElement bookFeeRow=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Book Fee']/.."));
int bookFeeIndex=fee_List.indexOf(bookFeeRow)+1; //'+1' because index starts from 0 and webelement [indices] start from 1
String bookFeeAmount=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='charges']/table[2]/tbody/tr["+bookFeeIndex+"]/td[2]")).getText();
```